# Generically assigning correct Sprite based off score in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 10 sprites of numbers 0-9. I want the score to max at 999. I don't want to bruteforce code the changing of the sprites like I just started doing so:

```
    if (TextHandler.score <= 9)
    {

        ones = Resources.Load<UnityEngine.Sprite>(tuples[TextHandler.score]);
    }

    if (TextHandler.score > 9)
    {
        ones = Resources.Load<UnityEngine.Sprite>(tuples[(TextHandler.score - 10)]);
        tens = Resources.Load<UnityEngine.Sprite>(tuples[(TextHandler.score - 10) + 1]);

    }
    if (TextHandler.score > 19) {
        ones = Resources.Load<UnityEngine.Sprite>(tuples[(TextHandler.score - 20)]);
        tens = Resources.Load<UnityEngine.Sprite>(tuples[(TextHandler.score - 20) + 1]);
    }
    rOnes.sprite = ones;
    rTens.sprite = tens;
    rHuns.sprite = hundreds;
```

I am trying to find a formula to maybe loop through and do all this code up to 999 without writing it all out. **Some background:** ones, tens, and huns(not shown) are all of type `Sprite`. rOnes, rTens, and rHuns are Sprite renderers. I assign the image based on the score, which is grabbed from `TextHandler.score`. `Tuples` is an array of `String`s. They are just strings to the directory of the textures in sequential order. Example: `tuples[0]` would return the texture for 0.

**Question:** Is there a generic way I can assign the correct `Sprite`s without bruteforcing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution I thought up if you're limited to 999:

```
var score = TextHandler.score; //Int32 I'm assuming
ones = Resources.Load<UnityEngine.Sprite>(tuples[score % 10]);
score /= 10;
// If the score is less than 10 this will be zero
tens = Resources.Load<UnityEngine.Sprite>(tuples[score % 10]);
score /= 10;
// If the score is less than 100 this will be zero
hundreds = Resources.Load<UnityEngine.Sprite>(tuples[score % 10]);
```

...this can be generalized to higher magnitudes naturally with a `while` loop since this pattern repeats itself so much. In the future, when you need to do something with each digit in an integer, consider using the modulus function to "get" the rightmost digit and then perform integer division by 10 to get the remaining digits by left-shifting (you'll get them from right to left if you divide in this manner). This can be performed for arbitrary integers (it'll even work for arbitrarily large BigIntegers).

Comment: I wasn't able to post this for a while so what you posted is where I ended up already. However, I never thought of using modules as getting "the rightmost digit" that's pretty smart. I will do some more testing and see if this leads me to the solution.